# android datepicker january month output zero

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm creating date picker and follow some guidelines and answer here in stackoverflow. But apparently, my date picker month start with zero.

For example:
if I choose January 24, 2018, it will output as 24/0/2018.

Can someone teach me how to resolve this ? and change date format as "mm-dd-yyyy". Thankyou

```
    etin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckin);
    etin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    etout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckout);
    etout.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    etin.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });

    etout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showToDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
}

public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void  showToDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ToDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class  DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        c.set(2018,11 ,31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        etin.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    }
}

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    // Calendar startDateCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        String getfromdate = etin.getText().toString().trim();
        String getfrom[] = getfromdate.split("/");
        int year,month,day;
        year= Integer.parseInt(getfrom[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[1]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[0]);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day + 1);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

        c.set(2018,11, 31);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();


        etout.setText(day + "/" + month  + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing to resolve, really. Months are generally zero-based throughout Java and Android. January should be `0`.

Comment: so how can I show or output "1" if i selected january.
for example 
check-in : 01/20/2018

Comment: Since you're already creating a `Calendar`, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the `Date` you're getting from that `Calendar` in `onDateSet()` to get the desired text format. `Calendar`'s months are zero-based, as well, so it'll be expecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1 to every set month and store the result into a new variable, then use that variable as the selected month. Like this: `int mont = month+1;`. Moreover, I have modified the last fragment of your code to put my explanation in action.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        int mont = month+1;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, mont, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();


        etout.setText(day + "/" + mont  + "/" + year);
    }
```

The `mont` is the new variable.

**Update**: To get similar result in your checkin, do the same thing in the code that gets the date. Like this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    int mont = month +1;

    etin.setText(day + "/" + mont + "/" + year);
}
```

Comment: when i set it  into data set of checkin and check out. the output will gonna show
check in : 01/24/2018 
check-out: 02/25/2018, it increase 1 month into check out

Answer (score 0):

You are really working in at shifted months. For example you get sep-31-2018 when correspond to Oct-31-2018.

Comment: please elaborate on your answer